# Use a function before it is defined

Tags: python

I know that the order of functions in a script doesn't matter. However, this sample code doesn't work:

*main.py*

```
_FUNCTIONS = (_foo, _bar) 

def myfunc():
    for f in _FUNCTIONS:
        print(f())

def _foo():
    return False

def _bar():
    return True

myfunc()
```

provides the following error

```
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    _FUNCTIONS = (_foo, _bar) 
NameError: name '_foo' is not defined
```

However, if I don't use `_FUNCTIONS` and inject `(_foo, _bar)` into a code this will work:

```
def myfunc():
    for f in (_foo, _bar):
        print(f())

def _foo():
    return False

def _bar():
    return True

myfunc()
```

**Why the first example doesn't work?**

**How can I extract the list of functions in a variable and put it on the top of the script?**

Comment: "I know that the order of functions in a script doesn't matter."—Yeah it does. You can't store a reference to something before it is defined.

Comment: in the second code snipped, the function is executed *after* the variables are defined. Try running `myfunc()` directly after the definition of `myfunc` and it will fail like the first code snippet.

Comment: Think about the order of execution, not the order of the statements themselves.  Python will make an initial pass through your file, executing each statement at the top level.  The `def` statements will define a function, but not execute it.  By the time you get to the `myfunc()` call, all the functions are defined.  In your first example, you're using `_foo` and `_bar` before their `def`s have been seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually misunderstood it,
When you are using `_FUNCTIONS = (_foo, _bar)` , python expects `_foo` and `_bar` as a variable nothing fancy here, and since you haven't defined any reference to it yet, it's undefined, thus throws error.

In the second case, you're doing the same thing inside a function, by that time, the function is already available in python's scope, thus no error.

And as [@khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) has mentioned in the comment, *the order does matter*

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood that a constant is evaluated at the time of it's definition, not at the time when we actual use it (like in case of functions).